# Redirect page according to user and admin PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I have created a users table having username, password, usertype,email etc...The user type distinguishes user as Admin or other users.Now, after logging in, the getuser.php page is used to redirect according to the usertype.Please help me. Thank you.

Here is my getuser.php page:

```
<?php include 'connect.php'; ?>

<? 
$user = $_GET['user']; 
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['user'] = $username; 
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){     

 $sql = "SELECT usertype FROM users WHERE userName='".$username."'";
$result = $db->query($sql);

//the function num_rows() checks if there are more than zero rows returned
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   //echo "<table><tr><th>SELECT</th><th>ADID</th><th>ADName</th><th>ADCATEGORY</th><th>CONTACTNUMBER</th><th>EXPIRATIONDATE</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $level= $row['usertype'];

    }
}
    if ($level=='1')
    {
      header("Location: adlist.php?user=$username");
    }
    else
    {
     header("Location: post_ad.php?user=$username");
    }
}


 else { 
echo " Sorry, but you must login to view the members area" 
 } 
?>
```

Comment: The blank spaces/lines between line 1 and line 3 will kill your ability to use a header redirect. No output can be sent to the browser before calling `header()`

Answer (score 0):

scrowler's comment is completely correct

When PHP executes a file all spaces between `?> <?php` are considered as output.

In the example in your question:

```
<?php include 'connect.php'; ?>
<!-- this gap produces output -->
<?php /* ... */ ?>
```

Why is this a big deal?

To issue a redirect headers have to be sent to the client, these headers must be sent ahead of the body of the HTTP Response. This means that when you go to issue the redirect latter on in the program, it's already to late as the body has already started to be written to the HTTP Response. If you are using out put buffering the client may have already received some of the response.

A response header looks something like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Date: Thu, 20 Nov 2014 00:55:09 GMT
Content-Length: 10614
```

A response will look more familiar to you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Edit - Stack Overflow</title>
    <!-- ... -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- ... -->
</body>
</html>
```

**To fix the problem change the first few lines of the file as follows**

```
<?php 
include 'connect.php';
$username = $_GET['user']; // not $user = $_GET['user'];
// ...
```